# React Context and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-hooks

I am getting the following linting error from typescript but I do not know the exact reason why because IBlockchainContextValue already has its state property of type IBlockchainContextState, which at the same time already has all those loading, account... properties... Perhaps it is better to look at the code and the attached image to understand the Typescript issue.

```
// Blockchain context

import React from 'react';

interface IBlockchainContextState {
  loading: boolean;
  account: string;
  tokemonToken: any; // TODO
  web3: any; // TODO
  errorMessage: string;
}

interface IBlockchainContextValue {
  state: IBlockchainContextState;
  dispatch: React.Dispatch<any>;
}

const initialState: IBlockchainContextState = {
  loading: false,
  account: '',
  tokemonToken: null,
  web3: null,
  errorMessage: '',
};

const BlockchainContext =
  React.createContext<IBlockchainContextState>(initialState);

const BlockchainContextProvider: React.FC<IBlockchainContextValue> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [account, setAccount] = React.useState('');
  const [tokemonToken, setTokemonToken] = React.useState(null);
  const [web3, setWeb3] = React.useState(null);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = React.useState('');

  // Context Update Setters

  const blockchainReducer = (
    state: IBlockchainContextState,
    action: any
  ): IBlockchainContextState => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'SET_LOADING':
        return { ...state, loading: action.payload };
      case 'SET_ACCOUNT':
        return { ...state, account: action.payload };
      case 'SET_TOKEN':
        return { ...state, tokemonToken: action.payload };
      case 'SET_WEB3':
        return { ...state, web3: action.payload };
      case 'SET_ERROR_MESSAGE':
        return { ...state, errorMessage: action.payload };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(blockchainReducer, initialState);

  const blockchainContextValue = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      state,
      dispatch,
    }),
    [state, dispatch]
  );

  return (
    <BlockchainContext.Provider value={blockchainContextValue}>
      {children}
    </BlockchainContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { BlockchainContext, BlockchainContextProvider };
```

[Typescript hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlbSS.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have defined the incorrect context value type.

You are defining the Context with the following type:

```js
// note lack of dispatch
const BlockchainContext =
  React.createContext<IBlockchainContextState>(initialState);

// but you are instantiating the provider with:
return (
  <BlockchainContext.Provider value={blockchainContextValue}>
    {children}
  </BlockchainContext.Provider>
)

// which has a type of:
type ContextValue = {
  state: IBlockchainContextState,
  dispatch: React.Dispatch<Actions> // in your case this might be any ATM
}
```

The typescript error is correctly telling you that the value you are providing is missing all the properties from `IBlockchainContextState` because you are not providing that.

I would recommend simply redefining the context type to be the following:

```js
const BlockchainContext = React.createContext<{
  state: IBlockchainContextState,
  dispatch: React.Dispatch<Actions>, // probably need a type for your actions
}>({
  state: initialState,
  dispatch: () => {}, // initialise with an empty function
}),
```

Comment: Thanks!! That's definitely the issue!